# Error Checking If Folder Exists

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to check if a folder exists.  If it does, do nothing, if it does not create it.  I keep getting this error:

```
Missing expression after unary operator '!'.
At C:\powershell\Test.ps1:15 char:5
+ if(! <<<<Test-Path - path C:\Today\$DateFormat\))
+Category Info      : ParserError: (!:String) [],   ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorID     : MissingExpressionAfterOperator
```

And here is my full syntax:

```
#Declaring this variable as it will be used multiple times
$DateFormat = Get-Date -f 'MM.dd.yy'

#Checking if main folder already exists
if(!Test-Path -path C:\Today\$DateFormat\))
{
New-Item C:\Today\$DateFormat\ -type directory
}#
if(!Test-Path -path C:\Today\$DateFormat\))
```

Comment: This was just a typo and will most likely get closed. `if(!(Test-Path -path C:\Today\$DateFormat\)){}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a start bracket missing after the first `!` operator (between the two carets below):

```
if(!Test-Path -path C:\Today\$DateFormat\))
   ^^
```

Change the `if` statements to be like this, and it'll work:

```
if(!(Test-Path -path C:\Today\$DateFormat\))
```